# jquery Ui not working with overridden $jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, conflict

I'm implementing `jqueryUi` Datepicker in an application. Which is using `jQuery 1.7` and it's global selector has overrided using `$jQuery`. 
Which means we are using `$jQuery` wherever we are using `jquery`.

Problem is now with `jQueryUi`. when i'm adding reference of `jQueryUi` on my page. It shows `$` as `null` in `jQueryUI` min file.

How i should avoid this conflict and make it work...??

Comment: jQuery UI doesn't use the dollarsign internally, it uses jQuery, which hopefully you didn't override? Post some code and an example.